# How to recover Nexus OSS Realms?

Tags: nexus3

I have a Nexus OSS 3.15.6 and accidentally removed these two realms from its config:

- Local Authenticating Realm
- Local Authorizing Realm

How can I recover these configurations once a time that I don't have any access to Nexus's Dashboard?

I have restarted the Nexus system, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In Nexus admin panel select Administration > Realms and move

- Local Authenticating Realm
- Local Authorizing Realm

from Available to Active